# google compute engine OAUTH via REST/HTTP

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, google-compute-engine

I am building a connector to allow use of the Google Compute Engine for a Cloud Brokerage. I have coded the various REST/API requests using C and the various HTTP libraries that are already employed by the platform for connection to most other cloud platforms. I am quite accustomed to authenticationvia OAuth on other platfroms and also in using the various cryptographic algorithms for this purpose. I am encountering an obstacle in that each request for a token grant is responding with an HTTP Error 400 and a JSON message : { "error":"invalid_grant", "error_description":"Bad Request"}. I have tried many things and found several ambiguities in the online documentation to this effect ( https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#callinganapi ) and wonder if anyone could help me to resolve this problem. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. In fact I was using the HMAC SHA to digest the message contents prior to signing and it should have been an SHA256 digest operation instead. It is all working well now. The header and claim messages shown as plain text JSON structures work perfectly even if the encoded versions show different information when decoded.